# Need to fire an event when jsDatePick updates the targeted textbox

Tags: javascript

I have a asp:textbox control that is assigned to jsDatePick (works perfectly).  I now have a problem in that when the date value is written to the textbox, I need to fire an event so that something happens on the server (I was planning on doing a "submit" or __doPost).

I tried to  use their example to for delegation but that doesn't work ... I get error messages when I try to do this:

```
g_calendarObject = new JsDatePick({
        useMode:1,
        isStripped:true,
        target:"aFieldId",
      cellColorScheme:"armygreen"
    });
```

Any ideas on how to get the textbox to post when the text changes?  Obviously, it won't fire the textbox onChange event, even if `autopostback = 'true'`

Comment: What are those error messages?

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem... but I found a way to mimic an onchange event when selecting the date in the calendar.

Here is what I would do :

```
g_calendarObject = new JsDatePick({
    useMode:1,
    isStripped:true,
    target:"aFieldId",
    cellColorScheme:"armygreen"
});
g_calendarObject.addOnSelectedDelegate(function(){
    // write the code you want here...
    // document.yourForm.submit() or whatever you need

    // as an example, here I "alert" the selected date :
    alert($("#aFieldId").val());
});
```

hope this will help !